# how to pull url and pass variable to python 3's http.server

Tags: python-3.x, simplehttpserver

My google-fu is failing me, perhaps because it is late.

Given the code below, I need to take everything after the domain.tld/ and parse it. It will then run against a database (in the example I'm using a dict, but in reality I'll be making a call to mysql, will that change it?)

Then, it will serve up a redirect header with that url.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class HTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(301)
        self.send_header('Location', url)
        self.end_headers()
        return

array["stuff"] = "http://google.com"
array["thing"] = "http://yahoo.com"
url = array[page]

server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, HTTPServer_RequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), `self.path` should return the url after the location of your server